# How to remove items from Breeze Query

Tags: breeze

I have a very simple problem, but I could not yet figure it out how to do it with Breeze.
I have an array of IDs, which I want to exclude from Breeze Query. In SQL, I would do

```
SELECT *
FROM Items
WHERE ID NOT IN [...Array...]
```

How do I do the same with Breeze? Is there an operator to do this, or how can I do this manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple predicates to your Breeze query.  Be careful of adding too many this way, but this is a perfect example of how we could do this -

```
function getAllTodos(todoIds) {
    var Predicate = breeze.Predicate;
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("Todos")
            .orderBy("CreatedAt");

    var compoundPredicates;
    if (todoIds) {
        var criteriaPredicate;
        $.each(todoIds(), function(index, item) {
            criteriaPredicate = (index === 0)
                ? Predicate.create('todoId', '!=', item)
                : criteriaPredicate.or('todoId', '!=', item);
            if (Predicate.isPredicate(criteriaPredicate)) {
                compoundPredicates = compoundPredicates.and(criteriaPredicate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This (or something similar) allows you to compound predicates together and get all todo's where the ID is not equal to a value found in an array.